# #1005 - Can't create table 'smartools.sales_flat_quote_item' (errno: -1)

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am getting error when importing database to server.

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'smartools.sales_flat_quote_item' (errno: -1)
```

> CREATE TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` ( `item_id` int( 10 ) UNSIGNED
>   NOT NULL COMMENT 'Item Id', `quote_id` int( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Quote Id', `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Created At', `updated_at`
>   timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Updated At',
>   `product_id` int( 10 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Id',
>   `store_id` smallint( 5 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Store Id',
>   `parent_item_id` int( 10 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Parent Item
>   Id', `is_virtual` smallint( 5 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is
>   Virtual', `sku` varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sku', `name`
>   varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name', `description` text COMMENT
>   'Description', `applied_rule_ids` text COMMENT 'Applied Rule Ids',
>   `additional_data` text COMMENT 'Additional Data', `free_shipping`
>   smallint( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Free Shipping',
>   `is_qty_decimal` smallint( 5 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Qty
>   Decimal', `no_discount` smallint( 5 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'No
>   Discount', `weight` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT
>   'Weight', `qty` decimal( 12, 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT
>   'Qty', `price` decimal( 12, 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT
>   'Price', `base_price` decimal( 12, 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000'
>   COMMENT 'Base Price', `custom_price` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL
>   COMMENT 'Custom Price', `discount_percent` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT
>   '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Percent', `discount_amount` decimal( 12, 4
>   ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Discount Amount', `base_discount_amount`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Discount Amount',
>   `tax_percent` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Percent',
>   `tax_amount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Tax Amount',
>   `base_tax_amount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Tax
>   Amount', `row_total` decimal( 12, 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000'
>   COMMENT 'Row Total', `base_row_total` decimal( 12, 4 ) NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Base Row Total', `row_total_with_discount`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Total With Discount',
>   `row_weight` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 'Row Weight',
>   `product_type` varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Product Type',
>   `base_tax_before_discount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base
>   Tax Before Discount', `tax_before_discount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT
>   NULL COMMENT 'Tax Before Discount', `original_custom_price` decimal(
>   12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Original Custom Price', `redirect_url`
>   varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Redirect Url', `base_cost`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Cost', `price_incl_tax`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Price Incl Tax',
>   `base_price_incl_tax` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base
>   Price Incl Tax', `row_total_incl_tax` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL
>   COMMENT 'Row Total Incl Tax', `base_row_total_incl_tax` decimal( 12, 4
>   ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Row Total Incl Tax', `hidden_tax_amount`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Hidden Tax Amount',
>   `base_hidden_tax_amount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base
>   Hidden Tax Amount', `gift_message_id` int( 11 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT
>   'Gift Message Id', `weee_tax_disposition` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT
>   NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Disposition', `weee_tax_row_disposition`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Row Disposition',
>   `base_weee_tax_disposition` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT
>   'Base Weee Tax Disposition', `base_weee_tax_row_disposition` decimal(
>   12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Row Disposition',
>   `weee_tax_applied` text COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied',
>   `weee_tax_applied_amount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee
>   Tax Applied Amount', `weee_tax_applied_row_amount` decimal( 12, 4 )
>   DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Weee Tax Applied Row Amount',
>   `base_weee_tax_applied_amount` decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT
>   'Base Weee Tax Applied Amount', `base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt`
>   decimal( 12, 4 ) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Base Weee Tax Applied Row Amnt'
>   ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT = 'Sales Flat Quote
>   Item';

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Error code #1005 can be caused by:

- An existing table with same name
- A problem with your foreign keys

**Option 1 (An existing table with same name):**

You have to drop that table or modify your import key with a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` syntax.

**Option 2 (A problem with your foreign keys):**

Add the following line on the very top of your SQL script:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

And the following at the very end:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: I already did that.. When i export database that time I disabled foreign key check also i added drop table command.. But the strange thing is if i made a table with `sales_flat_quote_item` name this is showing that `table can not be created error code -1`

Comment: Something in the MySQL log? Did you check if such table already exists?

Comment: Yes i checked that table not exits

Comment: The same query works if i change the table name only

Comment: Check in your MySQL directory if you see a file named "sales_flat_quote_item.frm". If yes you may have a DB inconistency. If yes drop the whole DB, recreate and reimport. Ps.: Make sure you have enough space.

Comment: No i don't have this

Comment: Drop it and reimport.

Comment: Please read the comment.. I said i don't have `sales_flat_quote_item.frm` file

Comment: Yep, I've seen. I think you messed up something in your DB. My suggestion is to drop the whole DB and reimport.